# How to check if Node Js query is empty or not?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, object

I have been trying to check if a result query is empty or not, I have researched for a while now. The code below shows the query that I'm making and the two ways that I checked if it's empty or not.

The problem is only one block is executed and the other is not executed even if it's supposed to be executed.

```
db.each(`SELECT category FROM categories WHERE category = ?`, [category], (err, res) => {
        
    if (res != {}) {
        console.log("Not Empty")
    }else{
        console.log(" Empty")
    }
}
```

On the above, if the `res` returns something it executes the if statement, otherwise the else is not executed.

I have also tried using `Objects.keys(res).lenght > 0`, but still nothing.

can you please help me understand this better I'm new to node JS.

Comment: `res` is an array, not an object. So just `if (res.length != 0)`

Comment: when I ```console.log(typeof res)``` it returns type of object not array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like Barmar said it is an array that you get back so you can use

```
if (res  && res.length > 0)
```

Comment: when I ```console.log(typeof res)``` it returns type of object not array

Comment: Arrays are objects. What do you see if you do `console.log(typeof [1, 2, 3])`.

Comment: Ooooh okay,  I get it. But still when I enter data which is not in database the else part is not executed.